# Cortana Skill: Why doesn't Cortana read my prompts aloud?

Tags: azure, botframework, cortana

I created a skill for Cortana using the Bot Framework SDK and it works perfectly, the only issue I have is that Cortana doesn't read my prompts aloud, meaning that the user needs to read them himself. I didn't find any info on this so far, does anyone know if it's possible to make Cortana read the prompts and what I need to do?

Comment: Are you using Node or C# to develop your bot, and can you also please post your code.

Comment: I am using C#, I didn't post my code because I thought Cortana is build this way and I need to activate something somewhere to get it to read the prompts, what part of the code should I post?

Comment: There is a speak property that is generally used to speak things and may not be getting called as part of the prompt.  if you could post code on how you are calling/building prompts so I could take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to write a few more lines of code to achieve that!

```
Activity reply = activity.CreateReply("This is the text that Cortana displays.");
reply.Speak = "This is the text that Cortana will say.";
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-cortana-skill?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)